# QGIS install common components from network directory

Tags: qgis, osgeo4w

I am trying to establish a process where one machine within our office installs QGIS using the OSGeo4W installer with 'Install from Internet' as the download source, and a network directory as the local package directory. Then I want every other machine to choose 'install from local directory' and choose the network path.

The idea is that the packages just get downloaded once by the first machine, and then all other machines install the same components from the local directory.

I am having problems making this work, however. Firstly, if you choose 'Install from local directory', there doesn't appear to be any subsequent steps where there is a choice of which directory to install **from**. The same windows appear in the osgeo4w setup no matter whether you are installing from the internet or from a local directory.

The first choice is where on your local machine to install the program (ie the root directory - for example C:/osgeo4w) and the second choice is "where you want setup to install the local files". That doesn't sound intuitive for me. In my case for the subsequent machines I want to be able to select the network directory as my **source**. But there is no step in which that is obvious.

Am I doing something wrong?

I have tried a couple of times where I choose the network directory (ie my local 'source') in the second step, but I think this may actually corrupt the files that are already in that directory from the first machine.

Is there a document that sets out the process for my use case? Or will I have to download every installation from the internet?

Comment: If you are doing this for a computer lab or to be used by you colleagues, I suggest you use the QGIS installer, you can download it and store it in a network drive. There would be less congestion at the internet level. What same components you want to install in all the machines?

Comment: Thank you @GforGIS. That used to be our standard approach. However, I have migrated to OSGeo4W installer on my own machine because it is cleaner in the way that it updates the LTR and current releases rather than installing additional versions of QGIS (we previously had users with multiple versions of QGIS using the windows installers). Unless someone else tells me otherwise it appears that the process I was hoping to achieve isn't possible.